# Incorrect checking of fields in list using a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have the following code that seeks to read the file contents into a list (this bit works) and then display a message of acceptance, IF the bank details (user and corresponding number) matches.

e.g. if username: customer1 and account_number:1 is entered >> Access Granted and so on for each customer and account number in the file.

**File details**

```
customer1,1
customer2,2
customer3,3
customer4,4
customer5,5
```

**Code**

```
def strip_split_read_from_file():
   bankdetails=[]
   with open("bankdetails.txt","r") as f:
      for line in f:
         line=line.rstrip() #r strip removes the new line character from the right side of the string
         split_line=line.split(",")
         for field in split_line:
            bankdetails.append(field)

   accessgranted=False
   while accessgranted==False:
       username=input("username:")
       password=input("account no:")

       for i in bankdetails:
          if username==bankdetails[i] and password==bankdetails[i+1]:
             accessgranted=True
             break
          else:
            accessgranted=False


       if accessgranted==True:
         print("Access Granted")
       else:
         print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
```

**Error**

```
 if username==bankdetails[i] and password==bankdetails[i+1]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

For an answer, and teaching/learning purposes I would like the following

1. Correction with clear explanation of the error using the existing, provided code
2. Suggestions as to alternative ways to achieve the same objective in the most efficient method possible

Comment: The error is that i in for loop is not number it is iterator of bankdetails.
Try to print(i) and you will see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in bankdetails:` means that `i` will become every element in bankdetails, not that it will become the position of the element. If you want it to become the position, you must do `for i in len(bankdetails)`, because `len()` is the function to get the length of a data structure. However, since you take two fields every time, I'd recommend to do it with a while structure, like this:

```
total = len(bankdetails) - 1
i = 0
while i < total:
    if username==bankdetails[i] and password==bankdetails[i+1]:
        accessgranted=True
        break
    else:
        accessgranted=False
    i += 2
```

However, if you have lots of entries in your list, iterating over all of them can take a lot of time. To avoid this, using a dictionary is the best option: checking if an item is in it is a lot faster, and you don't need to iterate to find the value associated with it.

If you don't know how dictionaries work, it kinda works like a list, except they're not ordered, and the way you look for an item is checking the value associated to a key. Let's be more clear. In your file, you have:

```
customer1,1
customer2,2
customer3,3
customer4,4
customer5,5
```

The way to add them in a dictionary would be:

```
bankdetails={} #Notice that they're initialized as {}
   with open("bankdetails.txt","r") as f:
      for line in f:
         line=line.rstrip() #r strip removes the new line character from the right side of the string
         split_line=line.split(",")
         username = split_line[0]
         password = split_line[1]
         bankdetails[username] = password
```

This way, bankdetails will contain `{'customer1': '1', 'customer2': '2', ... }`

And, to look for the user and its password, you'd have to do this:

```
username=input("username:")
password=input("account no:")
if username in bankdetails:
    if bankdetails[username]==password:
       accessgranted=True
       break
    else:
        accessgranted=False
```

This will do exactly what you wanted, but much faster if you had lots of entries.

Comment: Out of range will be raised

Comment: Why will    for i in len(bankdetails):
          print(bankdetails[i]) not work?

Comment: Can you leave in your answer, that I will check, but also do it without using a while loop. I want to know the best way to iterate through a list (using a for).

Comment: @MissComputing, It will.
bankdetails[i+1] won't work, because i + 1 will be == len(bankdetails)

Comment: @Vadym - no unfortunately it doesn't, Error:     for i in len(bankdetails):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Can you paste content of file that you need to process?

Comment: if you want to use a for, you'll iterate through all the elements of `bankdetails`. Since you're using `bankdetais[i]` as `username` and `bankdetais[i + 1]` as `password`, if you use a for loop, you will get `bankdetais[i]` as `password` and `bankdetais[i + 1]` as the next `username` every two loops, which is wrong. You could achieve it storing the usernames in one list and the passwords in another one, then you wouldn't have that problem

Comment: ok nevermind, the fact that you're discussing something different than my solution is confusing me

Comment: Shinra - thank you. Could you please comment your answer so I can test/understand it. What was wrong with your total=len(bankdetails)-1 and what does the first line do (range). Also could you comment and explain i += 2

Comment: @MissComputing nothing was wrong. But you commented "Error: for i in len(bankdetails): TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" and I thought that was part of my solution hahah. To solve that error, you need to use `for i in range(len(bankdetails))`, but that has nothing to do with my answer

Comment: `i +=2` means `i = i + 2`. I do that for the reason I commented before: you get two elements of the list every iteration, so you need to add 2 every iteration

Comment: By the way, now I thought of it. Iterating over lists is ok if they don't have many elements, but imagine it has tousands or more. It takes too much time. It would be better to use a dictionary. Since it might be long, I'll modify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def strip_split_read_from_file():
   bankdetails=[]
   with open("files.txt","r") as f:
      for line in f:
         line=line.rstrip()
         split_line=line.split(",")
         for field in split_line:
            bankdetails.append(field)

   accessgranted=False

   i = 0                               #1
   while accessgranted==False:

      username=input("username:")
      password=input("account no:")
      if username==bankdetails[i] and password==bankdetails[i+1]:
         accessgranted=True
         print("Access Granted")      #2
         break
      else:
         accessgranted=False
         print("Sorry, wrong credentials")     #3
      i += 2
```

1) It will be the initiation of the total length of data contained in the file

2) if username and password are correct then print "Access Granted" before break else it will not get printed as the execution will move out of the loop after break

3) print wrong credentials" if data does not get matched and move to next iteration and give another chance

Answer (score 0):

What about something like (untested):

```
def strip_split_read_from_file():
    bankdetails=[]
    with open("bankdetails.txt","r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip() 
            pair = line.split(",")                          # 1 
            assert(len(pair) == 2)                          # 2
            bankdetails.append(pair)                        # 3

    accessgranted=False
    while accessgranted==False:
        username=input("username:")
        password=input("account no:")

        for pair in bankdetails:                            # 4
            if username==pair[0] and password==pair[1]:     # 5
                accessgranted=True
                break
            else:
                accessgranted=False


        if accessgranted==True:
            print("Access Granted")
        else:
            print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
```

Notes:

Lines marked 1-3 slightly change the layout of how you store the (username,account number) pairs.  Instead of storing as a "flat" list, where indices 0,2,4,6,... represent usernames and 1,3,5,7,... represent account numbers, you now have two dimensions.  Now, `bankdetails` is a list of 2-element tuples, the first of these elements is the username and the second the account number.  This is very similar to the layout of your file.

So before, your list looked like:

```
[username1, account1, username2, account2, username3, ...]
```

Now it'll look like:

```
[
    (username1, account1),
    (username2, account2),
    (username3, account3),
    ...
]
```

Line 2 just performs a (very basic) sanity check on the data.

Line 4 just renames the loop variable to `pair`, to better represent what will be assigned to that variable, an entry of bankdetails -- a pair.  (`i` is typically reserved for minimally-scoped integer loop variables)

Line 5 uses `pair` and accesses the individual elements of the pair -- `pair[0]` gets the first, the username and `pair[1]` gets the second/last, the account number.

That's all that's changed.  Eventually, you might look into making an `Account` class, which you could instantiate for each account, and would have `username` and `account_number` member attributes.  You could also use a named tuple for a similar purpose.

Additionally, you could clean up the flow of your program a bit, maybe something like (again, untested):

```
def strip_split_read_from_file():
    bankdetails=[]
    with open("bankdetails.txt","r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip() 
            pair = line.split(",")                          # 1 
            assert(len(pair) == 2)                          # 2
            bankdetails.append(pair)                        # 3

    return bankdetails

def evaluate_login(bankdetails, username, password):
    for pair in bankdetails:                                # 4
        if username==pair[0] and password==pair[1]:         # 5
            return True

    return False


# Read file containing account info
bankdetails = strip_split_read_from_file()

# Prompt user for login
username=input("username:  ")
password=input("account no: ")

# Test user input
accessgranted = evaluate_login(bankdetails, username, password):

# Show login result
if accessgranted==True:
    print("Access Granted")
else:
    print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the below code:

```
import csv
with open('bankdetails.txt', 'r') as file:
     reader = csv.reader(file)
     bankdetails = [row for row in reader]
```

This would give you the list of customers list:

```
[['customer1', '1'], ['customer2', '2'], ['customer3', '3'], ['customer4', '4'], ['customer5', '5']]
```

Now, you can much more easily itterate though it:

```
for customer in bankdetails:
    customer[0] would be your customer
    customer[1] would be your digit
```