# best way to search for two values using csv reader in Python

Tags: python, file, csv

I have the following **file** (bankdetails.txt)

```
customer1,1
customer2,2
customer3,3
customer4,4
customer5,5
```

and the following code that seeks to:
1. ask user to enter customerid and account no (e.g. customer1 and 1), and if matching the file details, to print "access granted", else "denied".

**The code is as follows.** (note the ? where I do not know how to proceed)

```
def read_from_file_csv_method2():
   accessgranted=False
   while accessgranted==False:
      with open("bankdetails.txt","r") as f:
         reader=csv.reader(f)
         for row in reader:
            for field in row:
               username=input("uesrname:")
               accountno=input("account no:")
               if username==field and accountno==?:
                  accessgranted=True
                  break
               else:
                  accessgranted=False

         if accessgranted==True:
            print("Access Granted")
         else:
            print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
```

Please could the answer do the following

1. Correct the error using my original code. Explain what could possibly be done to access the fields (by index)
2. Present any simpler ways to achieve the same thing using csv reader method

**Update:**
I am aware dictionaries are the most suitable, but I want to solve this using these constructs for this particular scenario.

This, below code, for example works but only for the first iteration (customer1 and 1)...not for anything else.

```
 if username==row[0] and accountno==row[1]:
```

the above was used in the code below ...but doesn't quite work still

```
def read_from_file_csv_method2():
   accessgranted=False
   while accessgranted==False:
      with open("bankdetails.txt","r") as f:
         reader=csv.reader(f)
         for row in reader:
               username=input("uesrname:")
               accountno=input("account no:")
               if username==row[0] and accountno==row[1]:
                  accessgranted=True
                  break
               else:
                  accessgranted=False

         if accessgranted==True:
            print("Access Granted")
         else:
            print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect checking of fields in list using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130345/incorrect-checking-of-fields-in-list-using-a-for-loop)

Comment: No, that doesn't answer my question and if you actually read that particular question (also from me) you'll note that it is dealing with an entirely different method of file handling. (using strip and split, directly with lines from file). This approach is specific to csv. Thanks!

Comment: @MissComputing Please see my edits and clarification below.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(open('filename.txt'))
username=input("uesrname:")
accountno=input("account no:")
new_data = [{a:b for a, b in zip(["name", "id"], i)} for i in data]
if any(i["name"] == username and i["id"] == accountno for i in new_data):
    print("Access Granted")
else:
    print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
```

A simpler approach involves and function and a for loop:

```
def check_credentials(users, username, id):
   for user, the_id in users: #here, unpacking from list. user is the first value in the list that is created via iteration.
       if user == username and the_id == id:
             return True #return will break out of the for loop
   return False #if the loop has not been broken out of at the end of the iteration, it will return False

data = csv.reader(open('filename.txt'))
username=input("uesrname:")
accountno=input("account no:")
if check_credentials(data, username, accountno):
    print("Access Granted")
else:
    print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
```

Without a function:

```
flag = False
for user, the_id = data: #data is the csv file. 
    if user == username and the_id == accountno:
         flag = True
         break
if flag:
     print("Access Granted")
else:
     print("Sorry, wrong credentials")
```

Comment: Ideally, I do not wish to include any more complexity for teaching purposes...no use of dictionaries or zip etc. Just with rows and fields and a for loop......surely it can be done more simply? Thanks for this though

Comment: Could you comment your code. It's not clear, for instance, what "users" is....? Please include it in the context of the whole code so I can see how it works. Where are you getting id from?

Comment: Where has users been created?

Comment: @pythoncarrot `users` is the function parameter that takes in the formatted csv file.

Comment: Thanks - useful, but can't this be done without a function by using just rows fields and a for loop...that's really what I'm after.

Comment: For your last answer, where does it go??! After with open("bankdetails.txt","r") as f: ....or somewhere else. Please specify. If I can get it to work, I can accept your answer, else the currentindex suggestion from pythoncarrot is interesting. Thanks again

Comment: Also, I did ask for the answer to include my original code and variables - makes it much easier to follow. This:  for user,the_id = bankdetails.txt:  gives a syntax error